# jQuery Form API not executing the Success Callback on ajaxSubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajaxsubmit

This is my success callback function but it doesn't execute:

```
function onComplete (responseText) {

    alert(responseText);
    $('#progressText').remove();
    $('#uploadImg').show();

}
```

And here is My main code..

```
var options = {
        target:   '#output',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response
        beforeSubmit:  beforeSubmit,  // pre-submit callback
        uploadProgress: OnProgress,
        success: onComplete,
        resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit
    };

    $(document).on('submit', '#MyUploadForm', function() {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);  //Ajax Submit form
        // return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation
        return false;
    });
```

Every other callbacks execute except the success one.. 
In my php code also on succesffuly saving the file in db i have set

```
http_response_code(200);
```

Comment: If you bind the error handler, what do you get? Have you checked network tab in console? Any error? Etc...

Comment: It returns the image link which i just uploaded `<img src="uploads/images/thumbnails/chanx/thumb_chanx15-01-31lighthouse_26507577.jpg>`